# Multiple command inputs - negative sides?

Tags: interaction-design

Multiple command inputs - e.g. button, hotkey, mousegesture and pie-menu-item all for one feature (e.g. making a text bold).

I can't really see any downsides. More a great benefit; different users prefer different ways of reaching the same goal. And I can't find any good arguments against doing so. Still, I'm worried that I've overlooked something.

Examples would be great.

Comment: Are you talking about multiple options to perform the same command/interaction on the same UI element?  Or something else?  It's not clear.

Assuming it's what I asked above, why would you give users the kinds of examples you state?  You say examples would be great, but I'd suggest you provide one or else you're not likely to get useful answers.

Comment: I think Vitaly has understood my question. My example would be making text bold in the four different ways mentioned. The examples I was hoping for from here were examples of software that use this, where it doesn't work well. Hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, these two links might be helpful:
[Feature Exposure vs. UI Bloating](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/feature-exposure-vs-ui-bloating), [Is it better to have more than one way to navigate to functionality or only one way](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/is-it-better-to-have-more-than-one-way-to-navigate-to-functionality-or-only-one-w).

Second, I don't think there's much wrong with it - as long as it's consistent, and features of the same kind all have the same number of triggers. E.g. if making a text bold has the four methods you mentioned, then italicizing and underlining must have them too.

Comment: The only thing I'd add is that every way to a feature that you add is one that you have to support and test against future changes. It likely won't affect your future designs on the same application very much, but it can add future development overhead that should be considered.